# Angular 5 Animations - router transition on browser history back

Tags: animation, routes, angular5, transition

I'm trying to setup a router animation that slides in one direction when the user click on any [routerLink], but when the user triggers a history.back() clicking in a button inside the page or when they click on the browser back button, I want the animation to go on the opposite direction.

This is the solution I got so far.

**Main Component Html**

```
<div class="inicio" [@routerTransition]="getState(o)" (@routerTransition.start)="animationStarted($event)" (@routerTransition.done)="animationDone($event)">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Main Component TS**

```
getState(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    let state: number = this.appRouterState.getState(outlet.activatedRouteData.state);
    return state;
}
```

This is returning state++ when the user goes forward or state-- when the user goes backward

**Animation Trigger Setup**

```
return trigger('routerTransition', [
    transition('void => *', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', height: "100%" }), { optional: true }),
        group([
            query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))], { optional: true })
        ])
    ]),
    transition(':increment', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', height: "100%" }), { optional: true }),
        group([
            query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))], { optional: true })
        ])
    ]),
    transition(':decrement', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', height: "100%" }), { optional: true }),
        group([
            query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))], { optional: true })
        ])
    ])
]);
```

**State control service**

```
export interface ItemHistorico {
     index: number;
     url: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AppRouterState {
    private lastIndex: number = 0;
    private isBack: boolean = false;
    private historico: ItemHistorico[] = [];

    constructor(private router: Router, private menuService: MenuService) { }

    public loadRouting(): void {
        this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(({ urlAfterRedirects }: NavigationEnd) => {
            if (urlAfterRedirects !== "/") {
                let last: ItemHistorico = _.maxBy(this.historico, h => h.index);
                let max: number = last ? last.index : 1;
                let next = max + 1;

                this.historico = [...this.historico, { index: next, url: urlAfterRedirects }];
                if (!this.isBack) {
                    this.lastIndex++;
                }
                else {
                    this.isBack = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                this.menuService.obterPaginaInicial().subscribe(menuItem => {
                    let url = menuItem.url;
                    this.router.navigate([`/${url}`]);
                });
            }
        });

        window.onpopstate = ev => {
            let hash: string = (ev.currentTarget as Window).location.hash;
            if (hash === "#/") {
                this.isBack = false;
            }
            else {
                this.isBack = true;
                this.lastIndex--;
            }
        };
    }

    public getHistory(): ItemHistorico[] {
        return this.historico;
    }

    public getState(current: string): number {
        return this.lastIndex;
    }

    public getIsBack(): boolean {
        return this.isBack;
    }
}
```

Obs.: The "void=>*" transition is working and the ":increment" is also working, the problem lies when the user goes backwards, although the state changes and the component loads without problems the animation don't trigger.

Tks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve the problem. So for anyone who needs a similar solution here goes:

**Main Component Template**

```
<div class="inicio" [@routerTransition]="getState(o)">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Main Component Class**

```
currentState: number = 0;
lastPage: string;
getState(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    let state: string = outlet.activatedRouteData.state;

    if (this.lastState !== state) {
        let dir: string = this.appRouterState.getDirection(state);
        if (dir === "f") {
            this.currentState++;
        }
        else {
            this.currentState--;
        }
        this.lastPage= state;
    }

    return this.currentState;
}
```

**History navigation control service**

```
    @Injectable()
export class AppRouterState {
    private history: string[] = [];
    private isBack: boolean;

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    public loadRouting(): void {
        this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(({ urlAfterRedirects }: NavigationEnd) => {
            this.history= [...this.history, urlAfterRedirects ];
        });

        window.onpopstate = ev => {
            this.isBack = true;
        };
    }

    public getHistory(): string[] {
        return this.history;
    }

    public getDirection(page: string): string {
        if (this.isBack) {
            if (`/${page}` === this.history[this.history.length - 3]) {
                this.history.splice(this.history.length - 2, 2);
                this.isBack = false;
                return "b";
            }
        }

        return "f";
    }
}
```

**Animation setup**

```
export function routerTransition() {
    return trigger('routerTransition', [
        transition(':increment', [
            query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', height: "100%" }), { optional: true }),
            group([
                query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], { optional: true }),
                query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))], { optional: true })
            ])
        ]),
        transition(':decrement', [
            query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width: '100%', height: "100%" }), { optional: true }),
            group([
                query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))], { optional: true }),
                query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))], { optional: true })
            ])
        ])
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up to those who arrived here. The solution does work as of May 2019. Just a few corrections and reminders to be made.

1. In Main Component Class, this.lastState should be this.lastPage
2. In you routes file, make sure to add data { state: 'PATH_NAME' }. The code needs this to cross-check on navigation history saved in the service.

Other than that, as long as you've used the correct syntax and added the animations to your router-outlet wrapper div then you should be good to go!